# Popup with blured background wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup

how can i show a popup with custom content and with blurred background
I don't know if a have to use popup or popup with something like custom control inside.

I want to achieve something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNIrl.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a Popup.

You can indeed place a custom control with background thats half transparnet, and with blur effect on it.

Just inherit from ContentControl and have its Content be the 'real' popup.

Comment: Or even simpler, just a UserControl with all of the above.

Comment: Just bind its Visibility to some property in your viewmodel.